# Decomposition of an open set

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory

Let **A** be an open set. Can **A** always be described as the union of (possibly infinite) balls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In metric space, for each $x\in A$, there is a ball $B(x,r_{x})$ such that $x\in B(x,r_{x})\subseteq A$. Having identified $x\rightarrow B(x,r_{x})$, then it is ready to see that $A=\displaystyle\bigcup_{x\in A}B(x,r_{x})$.

Answer (score 0):

In the Euclidean topology yes, because open balls are a basis for the topology. The definition you should look for is the definition of *basis for a topology*.

More generally, in any metric space, the open balls form a basis for the topology. But in general topological spaces, even the concept of open balls may not make sense.